# PHP page loads partially

Tags: php, html

I have a couple of websites which load no problems on almost every computer/device I have tested them on. However, when I try to load certain pages within either of these sites on my work PC from within the corporate network both websites produce some but not all of the HTML output. They both stop at the same point each time. There are no errors reported from PHP.

If I use my work PC but disconnect from the corporate network and tether my phone to the PC I can again load the page no problems.

My question is, what settings within the corporate network would likely be causing this partial HTML output? I am assuming some kind of time-out (although the fact that they always stop at the exact same point of their output suggests something more like a length issue). What I really need to do is understand how I can replicate the issue on my dev computer so that I can put in some handling for when the issue might appear. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could be a caching issue. It might be that the corporate network has cached what you are seeing. Try changing something really obvious and see if you see that reflected.

Comment: Do all affected pages share the truncation offset, or are the offsets just consistent, but different?

Comment: Siguza, The offsets are consistent, but different as you have put it...

Comment: Do you have access to a tool with which you can make raw HTTP requests from your corporate network (such as `telnet`)? If so, is the response there truncated as well?

Comment: I'll check on the raw HTTP requests this morning and report back

Comment: What I have found out so far is that I believe it to be related to the proxy server in the corporate network having gzip/chunked encoding disabled. When I disable gzip implicitly in the .htaccess file the pages stop loading at the same point even on my own private network. So, do I need to include flush() calls in my pages to handle those networks that do not have gzip enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Should be the proxy or caching setting of your corporate network.
You can check by inspecting the header of the http responses, for Chrome you can go to Network panel in Developer tools and check individual requests and responses.

Comment: Thanks paradite. I noticed Private network includes
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=299
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Whereas the corporate network doesn't include those headers and instead includes:-
Content-Length: 12097

Also of note, if I add the line:-
RewriteRule . - [E=no-gzip:1]
to the .htaccess file the page gets truncated even on the private network at exactly the same point in the final HTML output as they originally did on the corporate network.

Comment: you may want to try other compression methods or remove the compression, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not seeing the error because there is no error. I'm thinking that you are using a exit() function which is not showing rest of the page, you may have an if statement which is stopping the computers from corporate network accessing the rest of the page.

Comment: Definitely no exit() function being called anywhere in the pages having issues. On one page, it dies in the middle of populating a select input item with data from a MY SQL recordset. On the other page, it is dying in the middle of setting some inline CSS styles on a div. The main difference with the pages that are partially loading is that they have more php code than other pages within these sites (and those other pages load fully both within and outside the corporate network)